# How to auto start python script running in virtualenv using crontab?

Tags: python, cron

This is how I normally run the python script in virtualenv on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
source hibi/bin/activate
python -m hibiapi
```

Now I want to make a cronjob to make it auto start the python script on boot but I don't know the correct syntax. Can anyone correct me?

```
@reboot /var/www/api.adoreanime.com/htdocs/hibi/bin/python /var/www/api.adoreanime.com/htdocs/HibiAPI/hibiapi/ -m hibiapi
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/var/www/api.adoreanime.com/htdocs/HibiAPI/hibiapi/__main__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import __file__ as root_file
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Why did you include `/var/www/api.adoreanime.com/htdocs/HibiAPI/hibiapi/` and what do you hope it should do? Just take that out,

Comment: @tripless I thought I'd need to include the path to script module otherwise it wouldn't know where it's located? anyway I tried taking it out but it still wouldn't auto start the script on boot

Comment: Do you get an error message? You probably uncovered a separate bug. The virtual environment takes care of setting up Python's module path, that's what it _does._

Comment: I've updated the 1st post to include the error

Comment: If it works outside `crontab` (only) from a particular directory, you can `cd` to that directory in your `cron` job too, as a workaround. The proper solution is to fix the `import` so it works from anywhere, but without seeing your code, we can't tell you how.

Comment: (This isn't a forum; your question isn't a "first post".)

Comment: `import __file__` looks weird, what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a shell script to do this.

```
cd /your/module/location
source hibi/bin/activate
/full/path/to/python -m hibiapi
```

Save the above in a script name it something like cron_run_hibiapi.sh.

Make your script an executable by running:

```
chmod +x /full/path/to/cron_run_hibiapi.sh
```

Open crontab using crontab -e and add the following line to the bottom.

```
@reboot /bin/bash -c "/full/path/to/cron_run_hibiapi.sh" &
```

This is untested but I believe it should work.